# Blockchain transaction automation

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix, decentralized-applications

How remix IDE execute transaction automatically
I want to develop a dapp on goerli which do not ask the user to confirm or sign the transaction how is it possible and all functions should be called by two persons student and owner (owner add student address in contract)

I need a solution that all added student and owner transaction handled on server side

Answer (score 0):

The Remix VM emulator knows the private key of the transaction sender, so it's able to sign and broadcast the transaction.

In order to send the transaction for the user, you'll need to know their private key.

The following snippet in `web3js` signs the transaction for the user and sends it to a node provider to broadcast it to the rest of the network.

```
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add("<user_private_key>");

// https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.1/web3-eth-contract.html
myContract.methods.foo().send({from: "<user_address>"});
```

If the private key is stored in user's MetaMask or other wallet and the user didn't give you the key, they will need to sign the transaction manually.

---

Goerli is a PoA (Proof of Authority) network, which means that blocks on this network are created by a closed group of block producers.

Unless you're in this closed group, you'll need to wait for any of them to pick up the transaction from the mempool and produce a block that contains this transaction.

Remix VM uses a feature called automining - whenener it learns there is new transaction, it produces a new block containing this transaction. However this feature is by design only available on emulated networks - not on public testnets.